# rsync ignoring --SUFFIX option

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -auve ssh --backup --suffix='2008-10-03-1514539' --backup-dir='/tmp/' module.pm root@web1:/path/to/module.pm
```

I run this command without the --backup-dir option and when it copies the file over, it creates a backup with a current timestamp. When I include the --backup-dir option, it makes the backup into the /tmp/ directory but never attaches my suffix.

There is nothing in the [manual](http://samba.anu.edu.au/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) to suggest that you can't use both these options together. I've played around with the order also and nothing seems to fix it.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: why did you add the linux tag? rsync is a UNIX tool.

Answer (score 2):

the manual says:

> --backup                make backups (see --suffix & --backup-dir)
>
> --backup-dir=DIR        make backups into hierarchy based in DIR
>
> --suffix=SUFFIX         backup suffix (default ~ w/o --backup-dir)

so it seems that you can use one or the other, not both (as I guess you want a way to determine what's a backup you use a suffix or a directory).

As a way to fix this, why don't you keep the suffix and modify the destination to include the backup directory.

Comment: From what I can see, the manual is saying that the --suffix option defaults to "~" without a --backup-dir (which it does). When you specify a backup-dir, then it "defaults" to an empty string, but you should still be able to specify a custom one.

Comment: yeah i did, as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: possibly, but I read it as "default suffix is ~, unless you have used the backup dir option instead". Its not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like this

```
# Backup
mkdir -p /tmp/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/
rsync -avz /tmp/`date --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date --date=yesterday +\%A`/ /tmp/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/
rsync -avz -e ssh root@web1:/path/to/module.pm /tmp/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/
```